# Contact form validation and email send. Works. How to do things better?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

This code works and works well although I know there are definitely some redundancies and better ways to do things.  For one, instead of using form action=mypage.php, I have all the php with all my html code.  When I tried to have it all in mypage.php, none of the variables would be found in $_POST.  Though isset would result to true on $_POST.  So... weird, and screw it, I put it in with the html.  I was trying with WAMP, but wouldn't work on the server either.

Another issue, refresh of the page after submission will send another email as well, which might be resolved if I solve the form action issue above.

How's my validation?  Anything recommended to improve the process or security?

```
<h1><div class="titleWrapper"><div class="titleContact">Contact</div></div></h1>

      <div class="contact">
          <ul class="contactColumn">
            <li>
              <div class="fields">
                <form method='POST'>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="50">
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="80">
                  <textarea name ="message" placeholder="Your Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Message'" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="copy" style="display: inline-block;float:left"><span style="float:left;padding:17px 0 0 5px">Send me a copy</span>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="contactColumn">
            <div class="rightSide">
              <p>
                Still have questions?
              </p>
              <p>
                Need more information?
              </p>
              <p>
                Feel free to contact us!
              </p>
            </div>
          </ul>

          <?php
          // define variables and set to empty values
          $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
          $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

          if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
             if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
               $nameErr = "Name is required";
             } else {
               $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
               // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
               if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                 $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed in your name";
               }
             }

             if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
               $emailErr = "Email is required";
             } else {
               $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
               // check if e-mail address is well-formed
               if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                 $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
               }
             }

             if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
               $comment = "";
             } else {
               $comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);
             }
             if (empty($nameErr) && empty($emailErr)){
               $to = "myemail@email.com";
               $subject = "Contact form submission";
               $subject2 = "Copy of your contact form";
               $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
               $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

               $headers = "From:" . $email;
               $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
               mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

               if (isset($_POST['copy'])) {
                 mail($email,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
               }
               echo   "<div class='errorMessageWrapper'><div class='errorMessage'><div style='color:#333'>
                       Thank you for contacting us " .
                       $name .
                       ". We will be in touch shortly. </div></div>";
               // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
             }
             if (!empty($nameErr)) {
               echo "<div class='errorMessageWrapper'><div class='errorMessage'><li style='list-style-type: circle;'>" . $nameErr . "</li></div></div>";
             }
             if (!empty($emailErr)) {
               echo "<div class='errorMessageWrapper'><div class='errorMessage'><li style='list-style-type: circle;'>" . $emailErr . "</li></div></div>";
             }
          }

          function test_input($data) {
             $data = trim($data);
             $data = stripslashes($data);
             $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
             return $data;
          }
          ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: Refreshing a page after a post request will always send the same post request again unless you cancel it in the browser. That's just the way it works.

Comment: Right, so the form action to a new .php page would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking to make the send email simpler with less code i would suggest PHPMailer it is less code and easier to use.

Take a look at the documentation for PHPMailer at: [PHPMAILER DOCUMENTATION](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial)

PHPMailer should make it easier to read if you understand PHPMailer, and very simple to write.

HERE IS A EXAMPLE:

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

$mail->addAddress("recipient1@example.com", "Recipient Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Here is a link for the the sending emails with PHPMailer: [Link](http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/)